# Parse XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

i want to parse following xml tags

```
<gains>5.640244e+03 5.640322e+03 5.640402e+03 5.640480e+03 5.640560e+03 </gains>
```

using c++..

can any one help me??

Answer (score 1):

No, because you haven't told us what the output of the parser should be for this example.

To design a parser you should give the rules of the grammar (informally is fine) and then one or more examples.  The examples aren't the grammar, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the OP is needing assistance with c++ stream processing of scientific notation.  In that case, please see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/scientific/ for some helpful hints.

Otherwise, I agree with Ben Voigt, need more information/context in order to be of further assistance.